# how many times can deploy website using firebase spark plan?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to know How many times can freely deploy project using firebase hosting spark plan?

I search google this problem after i found this answer. any one can explain?

" Firebase imposes hard limits on the number of simultaneous connections to your app's database. These limits are in place to protect both Firebase and our users from abuse. The Spark plan limit is 100 and cannot be raised. "

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit on the number of times you can deploy a web site to Firebase Hosting, neither on the paid plan nor on the free plan. The only limits are documented on Firebase's [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing#hosting) and are (on the free plan) around the storage size (10GB) and bandwidth (360MB/day).

Each deploy adds to your storage size though, so if each deploy of your site is 100MB, you will run out of space after 100 deploys and further deploys will start failing. See [firebase free hosting limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568065/firebase-free-hosting-limits)

At this point you can clean up your older deploys through the Firebase CLI or console, to make space for new ones. For more on that, see [How to clean old deployed versions in Firebase hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049653/how-to-clean-old-deployed-versions-in-firebase-hosting)